# Data structure for implementing alpha-beta pruning algorithm (2-ply game)

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, nodes, alpha-beta-pruning

So I've a general idea for implementing alpha-beta. I know I have to use nodes and linked lists for building the tree. But I can't visualize how to keep track. For example, each node in the 2 ply game will have a parents and 3 children. The root node only has children and no parent.
I need a headstart on how to create 2 classes - 1 for tree and 1 for Node data structure for representing this tree which can keep track of parent and child AND the position.

A nudge in the right way to code these 2 classes will be appreciated. The main algorithm will be easy if I get to understand how to store and represent the data.

```
public class tree{
  public Node parent;
  public Node child;

  public Tree(Node parent, Node child){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.child = child;
  }
}
```

^This is my initial idea. Don't know if I'm on the right track.
My main question is --- How do i store tree information for alpha beta pruning? I'm getting confused with representing the data that's all.

Comment: what is you problem? If you need to store 3 children in each node, consider using `Node[] children`. Tree itself will be a `Node root` having `parent = null`

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Okay can you give me a snippet of what the Node class will look like in that case? Will there be next/prev pointer like the usual?

Comment: @foxtrot3009 how you define prev and next in a tree?